# Windows Task Scheduler - Windows Server 2000

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

All,

I need to schedule a task (batch script) to run once per minute, every day.
Looking at the Task Scheduler, I see the minimum repeat interval for a task is 5 minute, which is located in the "Trigger" window dropdown.

How do you do this in the Task Scheduler?

Thanks Much

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown box is editable so just change the value to "1 minute"